# SSL server and SSL client program running on the same machine

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have developed two programs. One for ssl server and one for ssl client. The program does work fine when I run them on different machines. Just for the sake of fun I run them on the same machine. It throws error. I wonder if at all it is possible to run ssl server and ssl client programs on the same machine. I believe it is not possible but still I want to invite your opinions whether any circumstances it is possible to make it work on the same machine.

The error which is coming after running both programs in the same machine is:

** ssl_client1.c:74 Error connecting to remote machine
140216549042024:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:bss_conn.c:269:host=10.99.212.55:8080
140216549042024:error:20073067:BIO routines:CONN_STATE:connect error:bss_conn.c:273:

Comment: Can you please show the error.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to run them on same machine...once I confirm it, I can go ahead debugging the error.

Comment: If you use SSL/TLS correctly it can not work because the server URL/IP is hard-coded in the SSL/TLS certificate!

Comment: @Robert - the CN or SAN can be `localhost` or an IP like `127.0.0.1`. Both are valid per the [CA/B Baseline Security Requirements for Issuing and Managing Certificates](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1_1_6.pdf). That's the standard that CA's and Browser's have agreed upon. And all bets are off if the issuer does not follow any standards. Its anyone's guess as to what you will find in the absence of standards (and even in the precense of standards).

Comment: @noloader yes but user3206715 wrote that it works if the programs are installed on different machines. Therefore localhost/127.0.0.1 can not be the name in the certificate (if the programs really check the certificate at all).